# NSSpeechSynthesizer - playing sound

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm playing with NSSpeechSynthesizer class but for some reason the sound doesn't play. Here is the source code I use

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/`NSSpeechSynthesizer.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSSpeechSynthesizer *sp = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
        [sp setVolume:100.0];
        [sp startSpeakingString:@"Just testing"];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

And yes the speakers are on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is exiting before it has a chance to actually play the sound. You can check this by adding an infinite loop into your code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSSpeechSynthesizer *sp = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
        [sp setVolume:100.0];
        [sp startSpeakingString:@"Just testing"];
        while(YES);
    }
    return 0;
}
```